# Add new vulnerabilty module on honeypot dionaea

Tags: malware, honeypot

I want to install [dionaea](https://github.com/DinoTools/dionaea) but i am not sure about it's capability to collect modern malware. I see that it use old vulnerabilities modules. 
My questions are:

1) It is possible to add new vulnerability modules?
2) What are the steps to add a vulnerability. (From the begin, inclusiv from where to get vulnerabilties)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of implementing a vulnerability dionaea implements the protocol and uses libemu to detect and emulate the shellcode.